# How to calculate number of days between two dates

Tags: javascript

I have two input dates taking from Date Picker control. I have selected start date 2/2/2012 and end date 2/7/2012. I have written following code for that.

I should get result as 6 but I am getting 5.

```
function SetDays(invoker) {   
    var start = $find('<%=StartWebDatePicker.ClientID%>').get_value();
    var end = $find('<%=EndWebDatePicker.ClientID%>').get_value();

    var oneDay=1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
    var difference_ms = Math.abs(end.getTime() - start.getTime())
    var diffValue = Math.round(difference_ms / oneDay);
}
```

Can anyone tell me how I can get exact difference?

Comment: why should you get result = 6??? 07 - 02 = 05 days....

Comment: But the range of days from 2 to 7 is 2,3,4,5,6,7 = 6 days.

Comment: While taking difference I want to consider Start date also....

Comment: Well ... why not just add 1 to the answer?

Comment: The issue (if there is a issue at all) is functional, not technical. @Pointy comment is the answer. That's why some people ask why we are in XXI century.

Answer (score 906, accepted):

http://momentjs.com/ or https://date-fns.org/

From Moment docs:

```
var a = moment([2007, 0, 29]);
var b = moment([2007, 0, 28]);
a.diff(b, 'days')   // =1
```

or to include the start:

```
a.diff(b, 'days')+1   // =2
```

Beats messing with timestamps and time zones manually.

Depending on your specific use case, you can either

1. Use `a/b.startOf('day')` and/or `a/b.endOf('day')` to force the diff to be inclusive or exclusive at the "ends" (as suggested by @kotpal in the comments).
2. Set third argument `true` to get a floating point diff which you can then `Math.floor`, `Math.ceil` or `Math.round` as needed.
3. Option 2 can also be accomplished by getting `'seconds'` instead of `'days'` and then dividing by `24*60*60`.

Comment: moment.js will give negative value if a < b.  So, more robust calculation would be:

```Math.abs(a.diff(b, 'days'))+1```

Comment: Be aware to ignore the time-part - or else you would get different results for the same date but with different times (like from a date picker control). use moment(someDate).startOf('day') to explicitly set the time part to 00:00:00 before performing a diff (or any other operations that are sensitive to the time-part of the Date/moment object)

Comment: This works but it does not take the time component into account. Trying to diff between the following two pairs: (a="2017-12-24T00:00:00Z" and "b=2017-12-31T23:59:59Z") and (a="2017-12-24T23:00:00Z" and b="2017-12-31T23:59:59Z").  return b.diff(a, 'days') <= 7; both return true. Is there a way to include the time component in the diff?

Comment: @Roobie Updated the answer.

Comment: +1 for startOf() and endOf().  I've used this library for a few years and never noticed them before.  I always did +1.

Comment: @Supr Option 3 can not work in case if day light saving transition day falls in between a and b, in such cases Moment take care of day light saving transition using browser machine culture

Comment: Be aware that `startOf` mutates the moment. If you don't want that, then do `a.clone().startOf('day').diff(b.clone().startOf('day'))`.

Comment: Documentation: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/

Answer (score 91):

If you are using [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) you can do it easily.

```
var start = moment("2018-03-10", "YYYY-MM-DD");
var end = moment("2018-03-15", "YYYY-MM-DD");

//Difference in number of days
moment.duration(start.diff(end)).asDays();

//Difference in number of weeks
moment.duration(start.diff(end)).asWeeks();
```

If you want to find difference between a given date and current date in number of days (ignoring time), make sure to remove time from moment object of current date as below

```
moment().startOf('day')
```

To find difference between a given date and current date in number of days

```
var given = moment("2018-03-10", "YYYY-MM-DD");
var current = moment().startOf('day');

//Difference in number of days
moment.duration(given.diff(current)).asDays();
```

Comment: asDays() returned me some values with decimals. I use `current.diff(given, 'days')` so it rounds up.

Comment: @Vincent it seems that your are using this the wrong way. this is definitively the more clean solution  the result is right compared to the answer of @Supr in which a `1` is lost

Answer (score 22):

Try this Using moment.js (Its quite easy to compute date operations in javascript)

**firstDate.diff(secondDate, 'days', false);**// true|false for fraction value

Result will give you number of days in integer.

Comment: here is the signature : moment().diff(Moment|String|Number|Date|Array, String, Boolean);

Answer (score 20):

Try:

```
//Difference in days

var diff =  Math.floor(( start - end ) / 86400000);
alert(diff);
```

Comment: I think that's basically right but isn't it essentially the same as what's in the OP?

Comment: Because of the way he wrote it I didn't notice, but yeah, pretty much! :P

Comment: I don't like *magic numbers*.. it would be better if that number was broken down to a self-explanatory equation

Comment: This calculation is wrong when crossing boundaries of daylight savings time, because those days have either 23 hours or 25 hours in them.

Answer (score 19):

This works for me:

```js
const from = '2019-01-01';
const to   = '2019-01-08';

Math.abs(
    moment(from, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
      .startOf('day')
      .diff(moment(to, 'YYYY-MM-DD').startOf('day'), 'days')
  ) + 1
);
```

Answer (score 5):

Also you can use this code: moment("yourDateHere", "YYYY-MM-DD").fromNow(). This will calculate the difference between today and your provided date.

Answer (score 5):

I made a quick re-usable function in ES6 using Moment.js.

```js
const getDaysDiff = (start_date, end_date, date_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD') => {
  const getDateAsArray = (date) => {
    return moment(date.split(/\D+/), date_format);
  }
  return getDateAsArray(end_date).diff(getDateAsArray(start_date), 'days') + 1;
}

console.log(getDaysDiff('2019-10-01', '2019-10-30'));
console.log(getDaysDiff('2019/10/01', '2019/10/30'));
console.log(getDaysDiff('2019.10-01', '2019.10 30'));
console.log(getDaysDiff('2019 10 01', '2019 10 30'));
console.log(getDaysDiff('+++++2019!!/###10/$$01', '2019-10-30'));
console.log(getDaysDiff('2019-10-01-2019', '2019-10-30'));
console.log(getDaysDiff('10-01-2019', '10-30-2019', 'MM-DD-YYYY'));

console.log(getDaysDiff('10-01-2019', '10-30-2019'));
console.log(getDaysDiff('10-01-2019', '2019-10-30', 'MM-DD-YYYY'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// today
const date = new Date();

// tomorrow
const nextDay = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

// Difference in time
const Difference_In_Time = nextDay.getTime() - date.getTime();

// Difference in Days 
const Difference_In_Days = Difference_In_Time / (1000 * 3600 * 24);
```