# how to find difference of dates in years using moments js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

hi could you please tell me  how to find difference of dates using moments js?
here is my code

https://jsfiddle.net/FLhpq/6082/

```
secondDate "2019-12-01"  // formate YYYY-MM-DD;
var day = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD');
// difference of secondDate - date
alert('day'+secondDate - day)
```

Can we calculate the difference of years between two dates

**expected output**

3

Comment: there is a method called `diff()`

Comment: I need differnce in year as example it should give `3`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript : How to Calculate number of days between two dates using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9129928/javascript-how-to-calculate-number-of-days-between-two-dates-using-javascript)

Answer (score 6):

You can leverage on various methods i.e. [`diff()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/), [`asYears()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/years/)

```js
var firstDate = moment("2013-12-01", 'YYYY-MM-DD'); //Create date using string-format constructor
var secondDate = moment("2016-12-01", 'YYYY-MM-DD');
var duration = moment.duration(secondDate.diff(firstDate));
var years = duration.asYears();
console.log(years)
console.log(Math.round(years))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.5.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var a = moment([2015, 11, 29]);
var b = moment([2007, 06, 27]);

var years = a.diff(b, 'year');

console.log(years + ' years);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment.js"></script>
    <script>
        var a = moment("2016-11-04","YYYY-MM-DD");
        var b = moment("2000-11-04","YYYY-MM-DD");
        alert(a.diff(b, 'years')+" Year");
    </script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let firstDate = moment("11/07/2023","DD/MM/YYYY")
let today = moment(new Date());
let diff1 = firstDate.diff(today, 'days'); //for days
let diffYears = firstDate.diff(today, 'years'); //for years
console.log(diff1). //1
```