# How to get number of days between two dates?

Tags: reactjs, momentjs

I have a property `created_at` which stores Date and time of users that sign in for. So using Moment.js I want to get the number of days from "latest date" -"created_at".

```
moment(new Date()).diff(tag.created_at)
```

Comment: Have you tried `moment().diff(moment(tag.created_at), 'days')`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to calculate number of days between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9129928/how-to-calculate-number-of-days-between-two-dates)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get the number of days between to dates `a` and `b` as follows (using Moment):

```
a.diff(b, 'days')
```

Comment: Yes, It worked. But I did ”{moment.duration(moment(tag.created_at).diff(moment(new Date()))).humanize()+’ ago’}”. And it worked Fine. Thanks BTW