# How to check if two dates are more than 7 days apart using moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm trying to determine whether there are more than 7 days between two dates using moment.js.

code:

```
var start = moment(self.StartDate(), "DD/MM/YYYY");
var end = moment(self.EndDate(), "DD/MM/YYYY");

console.log(start);
console.log(end);
console.log(moment.duration(end.diff(start)).asDays());

if (moment.duration(end.diff(start)).asDays() > 7) {
    alertify.alert("Error", "Only a maximum of 7 days can be investigated.");
    return;
}
```

This works if the two dates are within the same month. However, if the dates cross over between 2 months the `duration` returns a negative value.

Example results:

[image]

Comment: end.diff(start, 'days') // gives you diferent in integer

Comment: You can use Math.abs() for absolute value

Comment: Docs for [diff()](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/). Also from the docs, on diff:  "If you want a floating point number, pass true as the third argument."

Comment: I'd just convert to epoch timestamp, and find the num seconds between the two, then divide to get days... https://jsfiddle.net/JS69L/1/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to calculate number of days between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9129928/how-to-calculate-number-of-days-between-two-dates)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`diff`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) method to check difference between two days and add `days` as second parameter to get difference in days.

```js
var d1 = "2019-01-10";
var d2 = "2019-01-20";
var diff = moment(d2).diff(d1, 'days')
alert('difference :' + diff)

alert('is difference more than 7: ' + (diff > 7))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```js
const d1 = moment([2019, 6, 30]);
const d2 = moment([2019, 6, 1]);
const diffDays = d1.diff(d2, 'days');

console.log(diffDays);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**With native JavaScript:**

```js
const dayInMiliseconds = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
const self = {start: new Date(), end: new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + 7))}

console.log(Math.round((self.end - self.start) / dayInMiliseconds))
```

Comment: This really only works if the two dates are set to about the same time. E.g. the difference between 2019-06-23 06:00:00 and 2019-06-23 18:00:00 will resolve to 1 day, even though the difference is only 12 hours and both dates are on the same day. See [*How do I get the number of days between two dates in JavaScript?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542938/how-do-i-get-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates-in-javascript)

Comment: If you want a day to be counted only if passed 24 hours, use `Math.floor` insted `Math.round`

Answer (score -1):

try this

```js
end.diff(start, "days") > 7
```

docs: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/

Answer (score -2):

https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/

```
var a = moment([2007, 0, 29]);
var b = moment([2007, 0, 28]);
a.diff(b) // 86400000
```

Comment: Don't forget to divide an round, to get days from minutes, so that it answers the question. This is just copy pasted from the docs without using the OP's code, and with no explanation

Comment: Ok, will improve my later comments, 
TY