# How to return relative time using date-fns from mysql datetime?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, date-fns

I'd like to add a relative time `... ago` into my react blog posts without using `moment.js`.
The post date is formatted in mysql `datatime` data type like `2023-02-01 21:25:33`

What I tried in the component this:

import { format, formatRelative, subDays } from 'date-fns'

```
const formatDate = (date) => {
  return formatRelative(subDays(date), new Date())

}


<p>Posted  {formatDate(post.date) }</p>
```

But I get error:

```
Unhandled Thrown Error!
Invalid time value
RangeError: Invalid time value
    at format (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:11517:11)
    at formatDate (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:1341:170)
    at Single (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:1396:36)
    at renderWithHooks (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:47842:22)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:51128:17)
    at beginWork (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:52424:20)
    at beginWork$1 (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:57387:18)
    at performUnitOfWork (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:56656:16)
    at workLoopSync (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:56579:9)
    at renderRootSync (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:56552:11)
```

I also could not find any relevant example in the [docs](https://date-fns.org/).
So I'm wondering how can I fix this?

Comment: I never used date-fns but according to the docs, `subDays` requires two arguments (instead of only one as in your example): https://date-fns.org/v2.29.3/docs/subDays

Comment: Maybe you can take a look at this. Seems to be doing what you want.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9129928/how-to-calculate-number-of-days-between-two-dates

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you don't need subDays

```
const formatDate = (date) => {
  return formatRelative(date, new Date())

}


<p>Posted  {formatDate(post.date) }</p>
```

Comment: Wrong. Still gives the same error: `Invalid time value`

Comment: Look: https://codesandbox.io/s/date-fns-playground-forked-7opk65

Comment: For some reason I still get error on my react app. Here is the raw time value: `2023-01-31T16:50:18.000Z` when rendered on my react app.

Comment: I understand, strange that this happens. Do you have a github (or similar) repository that you can share your project with? It would make it easier to understand the problem.